# Memory leak with setOnClickListener(this) and setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){})

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I read about [avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

to avoid context-related memory leaks, remember the following:

- Try using the `context-application` instead of a `context-activity`

And I have 2 questions :

1. If I use `setOnClickListener(this)`, will it cause a memory leak?
2. If I use `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){})`, will it cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

*1 - If I use setOnClickListener(this), will it cause a memory leak?*

Not necessary, "this" implements OnClickListener and if you don't leak yourself... for example running a thread in **onClick** will leak, using a non static inner class will leak, so the answer is setOnClickListener(this) will leak only if your implementation of **onClick(View view)** leaks.

*2 - If I use setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}), will it cause a memory leak?*

Is the same question, depends on what do you implement for OnClickListener.onClick... do not leak the class were you implement **new View.OnclickListener**.... and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can use both. Although, if you have more than one buttons (or any other widget), better to use first solution with getId() to diference them, the second one creates a diferent listener (object) for each button , so it reserves more memory. I dont think any of them causes memory leaks, because when you destroy an activity, and no links left for it, java GC gives back that memory (the listener objects) to dalvik.

hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late, but I'd like to add this to the answers above: It depends on what are you doing in the OnClickListener, Let's say if you're referencing the Activity which is the parent of a fragment and you're setting this OnClickListener for a view inside the fragment then you probably need to remove you reference or you risk of leaking the memory:

```
onSettingsHeaderMenuItemClickedListener = View.OnClickListener {
            GuidedStepSupportFragment.add(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, SettingsFragment.newInstance(), android.R.id.content)
}
```

for example, the code above is referencing the fragment manager inside the parent activity and is happening in a fragment, So the reference must be cleared or it will leak the whole activity and fragment together!

I'd prefer to fix this using the autoCleared delegation which can I picked from [Google architecture components sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/AutoClearedValue.kt).

So the whole implementation of the click listener when inside the fragment and needs a reference from activity will be something like the code below:

```
    class SomeFragment{
        private var onSettingsHeaderMenuItemClickedListener by autoCleared<View.OnClickListener>()
        fun onViewCreated(){
            onSomethingItemClickedListener = View.OnClickListener {
                GuidedStepSupportFragment.add(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, SettingsFragment.newInstance(), android.R.id.content)
            }
            findViewById<View>(R.id.header_item_settings).setOnClickListener(onSettingsHeaderMenuItemClickedListener)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not leak because garbage collection on JVM is not based on reference counting (as it is on iOS), but on ["mark-sweep" GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection).